# How to make a closable blog post

Tags: html, css, web

I have a "What's New" page on my website, and I want users to be able to hide and show the post using a button/a href link text. The code has been edited into the post below.

HTML:

```
<p>Post name</p>
<button class="visi" onclick="toggleVis()">+</button>
<div id="post-container" hidden>
<p class="post-text">Test sample paragraph = srve function private</p>
<img src="error.jpeg" alt="error" style="width:auto;height:200px">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggleVis() {
    var x = document.getElementById("post-container");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.visi {
    width:auto;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#79E119;
    border:5px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: If there's no code to show, you might just want to search for how to show/hide an HTML element and try stuff until you have some code to show.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the entire blog post with a `<div>` element, and use [jQuery's `.toggle()` function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show and hide it when users click on a related link or button.

HTML:

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<div id="blogpost"><h3>my blog title</h3><p>my blog content</p></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#blogpost" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```